# Access content via a LAN connected machine which is Django-WSGI-Apache configured

Tags: apache-2.2, django, local-area-network, wsgi

I configured my system to be able to deploy Django stuff using Apache on my machine(Ubuntu 11.10).I followed the instructions given at http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/12/11/installing-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-10-04/ .Everything went fine.I was able to run the url's i had created using Django on http://wsgi.helloserver and also on "http://hello.djangoserver" .
Now i wish that i be able to run the same from another machine(Windows Vista) over LAN.I configured the IP's as after running ifconfig
Ubuntu 192.168.1.2 and Windows 192.168.1.3
Using my Windows machine i am able to ping Ubuntu and vice versa.Also i am able to access Ubuntu's localhost using Windows.i.e trying.php lying in apache's home can be executed from Windows by hitting "http://192.168.1.2/trying.php"
However now how do i get "http://hello.djangoserver" to work from my Windows machine.
Had to submit URL's because i wasn't allowed to post more than 2 urls

**Edit:** In my urls.py i was looking for "^hello/$" which would invoke view corresponding to that,in my case hello.So on my local machine "http://hello.djangoserver/hello" works fine.
Now here's what i want to do.On my other machine(Windows) which i connect via LAN cable i want to be able to run "http://hello.djangoserver/hello" or 192.168.1.2/hello which currently don't work.So will Shane's answer https://serverfault.com/a/340154/103875 work?And if so how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alteration of the `/etc/hosts` file in that document is what allowed that fake hostname to function correctly.  For that to work from the Windows system, you'd need to modify its hosts file, too; it's located at `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: Worked great!Thanks!If some one bounces on this thread it may be useful for them to know that to edit C:\...\etc\hosts admin priveleges are required.So opening notepad with admin priveleges and then editing  this file did the trick